# Can i backup or export database of website that hosted in wordpress ( example.wordpress.com)?

Tags: wordpress, database-backups

As title, Can i backup or export database of website that hosted in wordpress?
On self-hosted wordpress site, it's ok. But with site hosted in wordpress, can i backup or export databases? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer your blog elsewhere by following these steps. Or, you can go to Appearance -> Custom Design, click the Fonts tab, and revert the fonts for each option to be eligible for a Guided Transfer. The Guided Transfer would then be accessible from Tools -> Export or the Store in your Dashboard.

Comment: Thsnk you, but if i import contents that exported to another website with other domain, i have to update links in content?

Comment: you can easily edit the link of any content in text editor